# I wrote a function called is_even_recursive(num), and it should return a Boolean. I wrote it with recursion. Why is this returning None?

Tags: python, recursion

```
def is_even_recursive(num):
    print(num)
    if num == 1:
        # print("odd")
        return False
    elif num == 0:
        # print("even")
        return True
    is_even_recursive(num - 2)
```

This function is meant to return whether or not a number is true or false, and I wrote it recursively (I know, unnecessary).

I expected the program to return a boolean, but when I print it, `print(is_even_recursive(123))`, it prints None instead of True or False. The conditions are being met, it prints "odd" or "even" before None is printed. Anyone know why?

Comment: You forgot to `return` the result of the recursive call.

Comment: In short: `return is_even_recursive(num-2)`